# What is the probability that we have exactly $3$ aces if we know that the first card is a black ace?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> We draw $5$ cards from the $52$ card deck (without returning). What is the probability that we have exactly $3$ aces if we know that the first card is a black ace?

In this task we have conditional probability. So let:

$A$ - we have exactly $3$ aces

$B$ - the first card is a black ace

Then: $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{|A\cap B|}{|B|}=\frac{|A\cap B|}{\binom21 \binom{51}{4}}$$
However I have a problem with $|A\cap B|$ because I know that in $\binom21 \binom32\binom{48}{2}$ I do not include the order of draws.

Comment: The number of ways to have two aces in the remaining four cards is (3X2X48X47)/6, i.e. the number of ways to draw two aces X the number of ways to draw two non-aces / the number of ways to arrange the order in which aces and non-aces occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know for sure that the first card you pick WILL be a black ace, the problem simplifies to picking only $2$ aces from $4$ cards out of the deck (which has a missing black ace).
$$\text{Total Number of Combinations}=N={51\choose4}$$
$$\text{Possible Ways to Choose 2 Aces}=n={3\choose2}\times{48\choose 2}$$
$$P=\frac nN\approx0.013541$$

Comment: Your solution is just the same as mine. Can you explain to me exactly why this is enough considering that black ace is first?

Comment: It doesn't matter that the black ace is first. Since it is a necessary condition, we can simply exclude it while calculating the probability.